# Prevent Windows from muting audio when locking screen

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have a Windows 10 v2004 laptop. I haven't installed any custom programs except Chrome, Notepad++, Steam, Spotify, Skype, Discord, and Bitwarden, all at their default settings.

I have a SteelSeries Arctis Pro USB headset. I haven't installed any SteelSeries custom drivers -- I just use whatever came with Windows. The only custom driver I have on the system is the latest GeForce drivers for the RTX 2080 Max-Q. I do not have GeForce Experience installed.

When I press Windows Key + L to lock the screen, my audio mutes. This is true regardless of what's playing: a video in the web browser; Skype; Spotify; anything.

How do I prevent Windows from muting my audio when I lock the screen?

Comment: Try installing / updating the headset drivers.  Windows 10 (any version) does not turn off Audio when the screen locks.

Comment: Is it only audio through the headphones that mutes? What about the internal speakers?

Comment: In general, this is not supposed to happen, unless done by a third-party app.

Comment: Installing the SteelSeries Engine software mysteriously made this problem go away. There isn't even a setting in the software to do this, so I am mystified as to why this happens. I wish stuff were more transparent about what it does on Windows.

Comment: Did you ever find out about this?  Every time I lock my PC, all the audio drivers disappear as if they've been connected.  When I logon again, they take about 10 minutes to load